# Copy Messages from one emailId(test@test.com) to another emailId(test-backup@test.com) in the same email server with same UID - java mail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

In need to copy Messages from one emailId(test@test.com) to another emailId(test-backup@test.com) in the same email server without changing the UID using java mail.

I can copy the email but the UID changes, so creates duplicate emails every time.
How can I fix this?

I have tried to match the UID's but it differs,

```
    for (Message message : emailFolder.getMessages()) {
       i++;
       UIDFolder pfCommon = (UIDFolder) emailFolderCommon;
       UIDFolder pf1 = (UIDFolder) emailFolder;
       int k = 0;
       for (Message msgCommon : emailFolderCommon.getMessages()) {
          k++;
          long uidCommon = pfCommon.getUID(msgCommon);
          if (i == k) {
             if (uid != uidCommon) {
                Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
                msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(message.getFrom()[0].toString(), false));
             }
          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize a protocol, add the UUID of the transmission in its request header, and decide whether to generate a new uuid according to its protocol type when you receive an email, but I'm sorry, I suggest you go to have a socket The community of tags goes for answers to questions, and they are very knowledgeable about data transfer.